# Pickout lines with defined datetime and save in a CSV file

Tags: python, pandas

I have given a small data frame that looks like this:

[image: dataframe]

In the first column "time" Unix epoch time in ms is given.
In the second column A, the rows are filled with data. 
Then I would like to define two times like:

```
t1 = 00:00:01.500
t2 = 00:00:02.000
```

My goal is to cut the lines from t1 to t2 and save them in a CSV file.

To convert the Unix epoch time to DateTime I use the following command:

```py
pd.to_datetime(time_ms, unit='ms').dt.time
```

Now I don't know how to define t1 and t2 as datetime.
I tried it as a string which I check with an if condition.

```py
time_ms = []
for i in df["time"]:
    if i >= t1 and i <= t2: 
        time_ms.append(i)
```

logically it will not work because the operators cannot be used on string data.

Comment: Based on given input, can you post expected output i.e. output dataframe (for saving purpose.)?

Comment: you can use ```datetime.datetime.strptime("00:00:01.500", "%H:%M:%S.%f")``` to convert t1 and t2 to datetime. but it might be easier for you to leave given data as epoch time and convert t1 and t2 to epoch time format.

Comment: Hi, 
I get a
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'datetime.datetime'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already converted Unix Epox to `datetime` and get only `time`

```
df['time_ms'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], unit='ms').dt.time
```

Now you have to convert string `"00:00:01.500"` to `datetime` and get only `time`

```
t1 = datetime.datetime.strptime("00:00:01.500", "%H:%M:%S.%f").time()
t2 = datetime.datetime.strptime("00:00:02.000", "%H:%M:%S.%f").time()
```

and then you can filter `DataFrame`

```
result = df[ (t1 < df['time_ms']) & (df['time_ms'] < t2) ]
```

---

Minimal working example:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'time': [0,1100,1200,1300,1400,1500,1600,1700,1800],
})    

df['time_ms'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], unit='ms').dt.time

t1 = datetime.datetime.strptime("00:00:01.500", "%H:%M:%S.%f").time()
t2 = datetime.datetime.strptime("00:00:02.000", "%H:%M:%S.%f").time()

result = df[ (t1 < df['time_ms']) & (df['time_ms'] < t2) ]

print(result)
```

Result:

```
   time          time_ms
6  1600  00:00:01.600000
7  1700  00:00:01.700000
8  1800  00:00:01.800000
```